# RMySQL - dbWriteTable() writes TRUE logical as 0

Tags: mysql, r

When using `dbWriteTable()` in the `RMySQL` package, logical values are written as `0`  regardless of value. I would expect that `TRUE` values would return a `1`:

```
# Setup
# con is a valid MySQLConnection object
> df <- data.frame(string = 'Testing Logical Values', 
                 t_lgl = TRUE, 
                 f_lgl = FALSE, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df
                  string t_lgl f_lgl
1 Testing Logical Values  TRUE FALSE
> class(df[,2])
[1] "logical"

# Test
# This schema has no tables until dbWriteTable() is called
> dbWriteTable(con,'test_table',df)
[1] TRUE

# Result
> dbReadTable(con,'test_table')
                  string t_lgl f_lgl
1 Testing Logical Values     0     0
> class(dbReadTable(con,'test_table')[,2])
[1] "integer"
```

Shouldn't the `t_lgl` value return `1` since it was `TRUE` and passed to `dbWriteTable()` as a logical?

Answer (score 2):

The `RMySQL` package is [being phased out](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/blob/master/README.md) in favour of `RMariaDB`.
Using `RMariaDB` I am able to successfully write `logical` values to a MySQL database like this:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), group = "my-db")

dbWriteTable(con, "test", data.frame(a=T, b=F), overwrite = T)
```